# Using a config file in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a fairly standard out-of-the-box MVC application I am building. The idea is for it to have certain aspects of its behavior change depending on a particular list of yes/no parameters (certain Views getting displayed or not).

As my experience is mainly with WinForms, my first thought was to create a XML file that would be serialized on startup. Is this a valid and intuitive way of interacting with a MVC project, or is there a better way of doing it? And, if this is fine to do this way, is it done the same/a similar way as you might with a WinForms project?

Comment: That's really opinion based and not an appropriate question for Stack Overflow. Find what works best for you and your application.

Comment: Depending on the config complexity, I find JSON to be easier to read and "config". Again, depends on your config.

Comment: It would depend on how often those parameters change and who could/should change them. You could use a Model and set the constructor to the yes/no's as required, and later override this with logic from other sources (database, administration pages, etc)...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Projects built using .Net will typically have a `web.config` file (xml) that will configure the framework for the application and allows additional user configuration that can be accessed programmatically at runtime.

If your configuration is trivial, you could use `<appSettings />` these are basic key value pair strings stored in the file and can be set like:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="foo" value="bar" />
</appSettings>
```

...and accessed like:

```
string value = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["foo"]; // returns bar
```

You could go all fancy and create your own custom configuration section in the config file but this is a lot more involved.

See below for some resources:

- [How To Create the Web.config File for an ASP.NET Application](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/kb/815179)
- [ConfigurationManager.AppSettings Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.appsettings(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [How to: Create Custom Configuration Sections Using ConfigurationSection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2tw134k3.aspx)

Comment: This looks close to what I'm interested in! I basically just need to create a list of booleans (for the moment - it may expand to more items later down the road) that I can access in the program in a way like @if(useView1){ //displays the view}, where useView1 would be the parameter from the file

Answer (score 1):

Create an entry in `<appSettings></appSettings>` of your `Web.config`. 
Example: `<add key="FeatureEnabled" value="true" />`

Then access it through `System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager` like so
`var isFeatureEnabled = bool.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FeatureEnabled"]);`

Answer (score 0):

in asp.net MVC you can use the Route and use URL to configure Application behavior read this [routing in Asp.net](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201.aspx) 
 and this from asp.net website [Routing](https://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions)

Comment: I don't understand your vote down.from his problem using the Routing is the best solution in the long run not using web.config. And what is the problem pointing out to proper way to do it in ASP.net Route because in Web.Config is deprecated in asp.net core

Comment: I'm not responsible for the down-vote but it might be possible that the OP doesn't want these options to be driven by the user i.e `certain Views getting displayed or not`.  But if they do, yes, routing and route parameters is a viable option.